Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Arrow displays incorrectly when the page is refreshed or accessed for the first time
I have a Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu using Vue.js and Nuxt.js :

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>

                <!--Dropdown-->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a
                    class="nav-link "
                    href="#"
                    role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Dropdown1
                    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'sort-down']" size="xs" class="move-up" />

                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">                
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <!--Dropdown-->

                <!--Dropdown-->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a
                    class="nav-link "
                    href="#"
                    role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Dropdown2
                    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'sort-down']" size="xs" class="move-up" />

                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">                
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown-items</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <!--Dropdown-->
                          

              </ul>

            </div>

For the Bootstrap Nav Bar dropdown menu, it will display a downward arrow when the page is refreshed or accessed for the first time. After a while, the arrow will be gone.
This arrow will also cause my dropdown-toggle to shift upwards when the arrows displayed.
Navbar capture 1:
refreshed or accessed for the first time

Navbar capture 2:
After a while

I tried to hide the arrow using CSS like this, but it did not work:
.navbar .dropdown-toggle::after { 
    display: none; 
}

I found that if I add "<ClientOnly>" for the nav bar, it does not have this problem.
However, it is not a good solution to render content exclusively on the client side, as it makes the nav bar display slower than the content on the pages.
Thanks for help.


Prevent Bootstrap's Default Arrow
Bootstrap adds a default arrow (::after) for dropdowns. To prevent this arrow from appearing:

.navbar .dropdown-toggle::after {
  content: none !important; /* Completely disables the arrow */
}


Use Scoped CSS for FontAwesome Adjustments
If the arrow shifts upward after a while, you may need to target the font-awesome-icon to ensure it doesn't interfere with Bootstrap's layout:

.navbar .dropdown-toggle .move-up {
  margin-top: 0 !important; /* Prevents upward shifting */
  position: relative;
  top: 2px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

